# interior-mounted adhesive window films that reflect solar heat

Tags: heat-transfer, glass, solar, reflective-coatings

Does a solar-heat-reflective film when adhered to the interior of a double-pane gas-filled skylight raise the temperature of the glass and, if so, does it increase it to such an extent that the glass itself or the seal around it would be compromised, if not immediately then over time? What are the physics of this system? The high-performance variety of film is said to reflect approximately 80% of the solar heat.

Answer (score 0):

Fitted some on two windows 2m * 1m.

No problems so far and we have had some seriously sunny days.

No actual data, but just touching the windows with and without the coating, those with the coating feel cooler. The reflection of the UV makes a difference.

As for physics - check out reflectors.